# Does anyone know what bike it is?

Tags: identify-this-bike, mixte

I received such a bike: Mallatte Sport on a mixed frame from 1987. Does anyone know the country of origin and manufacturer of the bike.

[image]

Comment: Is it MALLATTE or MALLARTE? It looks like an R to me.

Comment: Thank you! I have had started to renovate this bike.

Answer (score 5):

*TLDR;* I think, this is a bike from France built by a man named *Jean-Marc Mallarte* from the commune of Tournon-sur-Rhône in the South and he apparently built women's frames - and (co)owned a bike shop.

All I could find is this [site](http://cyclesud.free.fr/club/mallarte.html).

Citing the page (translated) since it might go offline given the dated looks ([web archive version from 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20070704033152/http://cyclesud.free.fr/club/mallarte.html):

> It is not easy for our traveling companions to find a bike adapted to their body type (unfortunately, the cycling world is still quite macho!). We will therefore try, ladies and gentlemen, to help you in this process.
>
> Women have different measurements than men: they generally have long legs and a short torso. They therefore need frames that are taller than they are long, to which specific accessories must be combined.
>
> But where to go to obtain this type of material? Each manufacturer offers its "men's" frames which it adapts, more or less well, by playing on the size of certain accessories, which, in the end, gives a rarely satisfactory result.
>
> At Cycle Sud we looked for "the" right answer, and we found it in the depths of Ardèche, more precisely in the small town of Tournon, with Jean-Marc Mallarte, a craftsman who has created a complete range ladies bikes.

I think, key is the last paragraph. Mallarte refers to *Jean-Marc Mallarte*, who seems to be a French frame builder specializing in women-specific geometry and built a range of bikes, so your bike is apparently French and from the south of France.

A [shop](https://www.tournon-cycles.fr/) still exists at the given address but there is no indication that it is still related to *Jean-Marc Mallarte* but if you want more, I would give it a shot, there. I'm not sure how good of a response you will get depending on the current owner's history with him (or previous owners) and their willingness to respond in non-French language.

---

Just as an anecdotal reference: Years ago, I bought a used frame which turned out to be a [Fondriest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurizio_Fondriest) from the early 2000s - the brand still exists but was sold to a Spanish company and since he is still in the business somehow, they forwarded my mail to Maurizio and he got back to me about the bike.

However, all I've got was "we sold this in 2003-2004 and made a few hundred of them", no information on the price and the model he was referring to wasn't even matching the frame's decals (even though I sent some good photos). So, don't expect too much even from contacting owners, that's the point I am trying to make. Time passes on and especially small manufacturers often don't keep book of all the frames they made and memory fades.

It might well be that the frame builder isn't with us anymore given the dated image on the old page (which could easily be 20 years old).